# How to remove weird string after URL in ASP.Net MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC3, I created my routes and compose my urls but I have something weird in my url after navigated in browser.

1. Url actually rendered: /controller/action/page.html
2. Url navigated: /controller/action/page.html**#.V7cdQJh97cw**

I think that maybe is SessionID but I can't know how to remove it.

Appreciate any helps!

Comment: Could you add a tad more description to this? :)

Comment: I already add more tags. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the RegisterRoute method of RouteConfig.cs file in the App_Start folder of your project where Default Routing rule is written there.

Route Rule:- ControllerName/ActionName/id

where id is optional. So you want to remove Id parameter ,then make Id=" ".

for example:-

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",                                           // Route name 
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                 // URL with parameters 
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" } // Parameter defaults
    );

}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. That isn't id formatted, I composed fully URL but when I browsed that URL and I see that string. Especially, all pages almost have that string at the end of URL.